# How could I extend these methods that use flexible arguments?

Tags: design, c#, object-oriented

### Context

Let's say I have a `Shape` class (I'll use C# for the code snippets) that represents a 2D shape, like a triangle or a circle. These shapes have an area, so I'll include a method for calculating it. Since I only care about the calculations, I don't want the `Shape` class or any derived class to contain any data. Instead, I work with flexible method arguments that each have a different implementation to get the same result.

For example: the area of a triangle can be calculated from its base and height, but also from its three side lengths using [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

```csharp
public interface IAreaArguments
{
    // Can also be empty, it's still independent of implementation
}

public interface ITriangleAreaArguments : IAreaArguments
{
    // Can yet again be empty, it's still independent of implementation
}
public class StandardTriangleAreaArguments : ITriangleAreaArguments
{
    public StandardTriangleAreaArguments(double triangleBase, double triangleHeight)
        => (Base, Height) = (triangleBase, triangleHeight);

    public double Base { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}

public class HeronTriangleAreaArguments : ITriangleAreaArguments
{
    public HeronTriangleAreaArguments(double side1, double side2, double side3)
        => (Side1, Side2, Side3) = (side1, side2, side3);

    public double Side1 { get; set; }
    public double Side2 { get; set; }
    public double Side3 { get; set; }
}
```

And the `Triangle` class could contain some overridden function `GetArea(IAreaArguments areaArgs)` that can be implemented like this:

```csharp
public class Triangle : Shape
{
    // Base area calculation from "Shape"
    public override double GetArea(IAreaArguments areaArguments)
        => GetArea(areaArguments as ITriangleAreaArguments);

    // Specific area calculation for "Triangle"
    private static double GetArea(ITriangleAreaArguments? areaArguments)
        => areaArguments switch
        {
            StandardTriangleAreaArguments stdArgs => GetStandardArea(stdArgs),
            HeronTriangleAreaArguments heronArgs => GetHeronArea(heronArgs),
            _ => throw new ArgumentException("The given arguments do not implement ITriangleAreaArguments or there was no corresponding method inside Triangle to calculate the area using the given arguments.", nameof(areaArguments))
        };
    
    // Area from base and height
    private static double GetStandardArea(StandardTriangleAreaArguments stdArgs)
    {
        var (b, h) = (stdArgs.Base, stdArgs.Height);
        return b * h / 2;
    }

    // Area from side lengths
    private static double GetHeronArea(HeronTriangleAreaArguments heronArgs)
    {
        var (a, b, c) = (heronArgs.Side1, heronArgs.Side2, heronArgs.Side3);
        double s = (a + b + c) / 2;
        return Math.Sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
    }
}
```

This way, the same function can be used to return the area of a triangle using different solution strategies, and if you use the data from one triangle converted into both arguments, the result should obviously be the same.

### Question

In the scenario above, I hide all the actual implementations from the person who consumes my class, but what if there existed some other method ([turns out there's quite a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle)) for calculating the area of a triangle with different input parameters? How could I change my implementation to allow new implementations to be added to the class, while still having a single entry point to calculate it (i.e. it only depends on the type of `IAreaArguments` that you pass into `GetArea`).

Would that even be a good programming style?

Comment: What's your actual goal here? It seems you are contorting yourself to avoid writing `abstract double GetArea()` in `IAreaArguments`.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to avoid having normal virtual dispatch do the job for you - or alternatively just provide a bunch of free functions?

Comment: What you have here seems to be some convoluted/inverted version of the Visitor pattern, where GetArea() plays the role of the Visit() method, and different types of arguments correspond to different Elements (I'm using the Visitor pattern terminology), and your different Shapes (which really model operations) correspond to different concrete Visitors (operations). It's just that you're dispatching manually, via a switch statement. But it doesn't quite work, because you cannot use those same arguments for other kinds of shapes, nor can you easily add new argument types / calculation methods.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I believe I've used a bad name for my class in the question, my goal is to have a generalised "shape calculator" that calculates properties of a shape using implementations specific to that shape.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I hadn't heard of that pattern before, it sounds like it would be a better fit than what I'm currently doing, especially if I can encorporate Greg's strategy in his answer below. Definitely checking it out, thanks!

Comment: @pjc50 I've not heard of either of those things, I'll check them out, thanks!

Comment: The virtual dispatch pjc50 was talking about is just a term for calling a method on a derived class through a variable of the base class type (the call to a virtual method is "dispatched" to the correct implementation). Free functions are just standalone functions (in other languages, it's functions that don't belong to any class / object instance, in C# those are static methods - think of something like the `Math` class from the standard library). I'm kind of echoing what pjc50 said: since the current design doesn't allow for extensibility, a bunch of static method overloads could work better

Comment: BTW, since you're looking into the Visitor pattern, be aware of the tradeoffs - the pattern makes it easy to add new operations (visitors), but hard to add new kinds of elements; see my answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/412392/275536) for more context (at the top), and a way to understand the strangely named Visit & Accept methods (at the bottom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting aside the question whether it would be simpler to design `Shape` and `Triangle` as classes with state (or not), let us look at your approach of creating individual calculators.

What strikes me first here is the separation of a class like `HeronTriangleAreaArguments`  (with specific parameters) and the related calculation `Triangle.GetHeronArea`. I think this is the core point where the design should be improved: each specific calculation requires specific arguments, so it makes IMHO **absolutely no sense to split them up**. Instead, better rename `HeronTriangleAreaArguments` to `HeronTriangleAreaCalculator`, and implement construction as well as area calculation in this class.

```
public class HeronTriangleAreaCalculator : ShapeCalculator
{
    public HeronTriangleAreaCalculator (double side1, double side2, double side3)
        => (Side1, Side2, Side3) = (side1, side2, side3);

    public double Side1 { get; set; }
    public double Side2 { get; set; }
    public double Side3 { get; set; }

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        var (a, b, c) = (Side1, Side2, Side3);
        double s = (a + b + c) / 2;
        return Math.Sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
    }
}
```

As you see, I introduced also a common base class (or interface) `ShapeCalculator`, with an abstract method `GetArea`. You may choose to create your inheritance hierarchy a little bit differently, maybe using an additional class `TriangleCalculator`, or some `ShapeAreaCalculator` if this will be used just for area calculation and nothing else, but I guess you get the idea.

This design makes it possible to use `ShapeCalculator` in some generic context, just calling an abstract area calculation, and still have a specific part in your program (maybe some factory) which does the construction process, knowing exactly about the kind of parameters and the related type of calculation. And if new calculations need to be added, you just need to extend the factory, but don't have to change the generic part.

Comment: I personally still don't see how this is different to defining different representations of a triangle. Don't get me wrong, this implementation is flexible and it makes sense, but in hindsight I'm not really sure what I'm even asking anymore. I just got so tripped up over what a triangle should be or what a shape calculator should do.

Comment: @JansthcirlU: you were the one who asked for an isolated triangle area calculation in favor of a full-blown triangle class, not me ;-) But a triangle class would probably require a more complex implementation, like taking the different parameter sets and converting it into some kind of normalized form. Moreover, wouldn't a triangle shape require some coordinates to be useful in your system? An isolated area calculation does not need that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just gonna have a good long think about what I wanted to accomplish exactly. Unfortunately your answer and Greg's are quite similar in spirit so I'm leaning towards accepting his because he was faster. I appreciate your feedback though!

Comment: @JansthcirlU: actually, I think Greg's answer has gone off-track with his last edit. The way he tried to use the strategy pattern does in no way solve the issue that the different formulas require different input parameters. Once you have a triangle object with a normalized internal representation, picking different approaches to calculate the area becomes pretty obsolete.

Comment: You make a good point.

Answer (score 7):

I would expect the sides of a triangle to be owned by the `Triangle` object. I find it very odd to pass in the sides as arguments to `GetArea`. This is more apparent when writing the code that uses your classes:

```csharp
Shape shape = new Triangle(20, 13, 32);

var args = new HeronTriangleAreaArguments(20, 13, 32);
var area = shape.GetArea(args);
```

Since the length of the sides define a triangle, I would expect the resulting `Shape` object to calculate the area based on its own internal state:

```
Shape shape = new Triangle(20, 13, 32);
double area = shape.GetArea();
```

The algorithm for determining area varies by shape, and therefore varies by derived type. I would expect the `Shape` class to have an abstract `GetArea()` method which is implemented in `Triangle`. This makes using the object more obvious and prevents silly programmer mistakes, like passing the wrong kind of arguments to `GetArea()`.

Small differences in the algorithm for different kinds of triangles should be a concern for the `Triangle` class. It should inspect its own state to determine the correct algorithm. This relieves the consumers of `Triangle` objects from memorizing the different kinds of triangles. To be honest, as I wrote this answer I had to look up the different kinds myself. I understand the concept of the area of a shape, but I should not need to know the exact algorithms necessary to calculate the area. I would expect the `Triangle` class to know enough to just calculate the value and return it.

Passing different kinds of arguments to `GetArea()` forces the programmer to know more about the implementation of a `Triangle` than is necessary with proper object oriented design.

#### Allowing Runtime Selection of Algorithm

The [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is an object-oriented design pattern that utilizes polymorphism to encapsulate a group of related algorithms. You could define one class per algorithm, and then pass it to your shape. The downside is you will likely need to know specifically which kind of shape you are dealing with:

```
Triangle triangle = new Triangle(12, 45, 22);
TriangleAreaCalculator areaCalculator = new HeronTriangleAreaCalculator();

double area = areaCalculator.GetArea(triangle);
```

This would break the `Shape` abstraction, since it doesn't make sense to use Heron's formula to calculate the area of a circle. Be careful to select the appropriate level of abstraction when you decide to separate an algorithm from its data. Casting from an abstract type down to a concrete type is an indication you are working at the wrong level of abstraction.

---

I also realize my examples of initializing a `Triangle` object are contrived. Each triangle has 3 sides, but each side also has a corresponding angle. This should be a concern for the Triangle class and its constructors.

Comment: Perhaps I chose a bad name, the purpose really is to be more of a calculator. In other words, given a shape, calculate its area, its perimeter, ... using calculations specific to the shape you're working with. So there's no need for the shapes to hold their own data.

A circle calculator class would for example also override the `GetArea` method but have an implementation that uses `ICircleAreaArguments` instead of `ITriangleArguments` or `IAreaArguments`.

Comment: @JansthcirlU: from an object-oriented standpoint, I don't see the benefit of separating the area calculation from the shape object. If that is the case, then pjc50 mentions using free functions, which in C# would be static methods on a static class. Why over complicate this with objects if those objects have no behavior?

Comment: I see, and I agree that it would be far easier to have let's say a `Triangle` with a constructor for base and height and another for the three side lengths. However, in the case of a triangle, getting the base and height from the three side lengths is possible, but not the other way round, so how do you differentiate what implementation you should use in your `double GetArea()` method? If I'd have to cover all the distinct properties using different constructors for each distinct area calculation in my original question, why not just let the method take care of it?

Comment: @JansthcirlU you can recover the side lengths from the triple (base, height, angle) for each of the three possible angles. So what if the area calculation ignores that angle?

Comment: Yes, my argument is that your use of object orientation is making life much harder for you because you insist on not putting data inside the classes that work with that data. You'd be better off renaming the "arguments" classes as TriangleBaseHeightData and TriangleSidesData, with no common base class, and just have functions that accept those.

Comment: @JansthcirlU: you will want to settle on consistent data for defining the triangle. You can define separate constructors that accept different variations for defining the triangle, and then the constructor can perform the math necessary to store the data in a single manner. If constructors require the same list of arguments, you can always use static methods on the `Triangle` class, which do the calculations. Then calculating the area might be easier with a consistent data model.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Or you make `Triangle` an interface, which is implemented by a multitude of combinations of sufficient data.

Comment: @GregBurghardt that's the thing, what if there's a constructor for arguments that cannot be converted to any other representation (unlikely but possible), you would need more than one implementation and somehow include that into a single method.

Comment: @pjc50 so you mean there would be a `Triangle.GetBaseHeightArea` and a `Triangle.GetHeronArea` method? Or do you mean ignoring the base `Shape.GetArea` method altogether?

Comment: @JansthcirlU or something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LmFMvY)

Comment: @Caleth the problem isn't having multiple constructors for the same entity, the problem is that the various required parameters for let's say the area calculation are not necessarily convertible from one representation of a triangle to another. The problem isn't that there are multiple ways to get the area, the problem is that I can't find a way to somehow make them converge into a single `GetArea()` method.

Comment: @JansthcirlU I'm saying have multiple `Area` calculations, that correspond to the data you have. The OOP way is to attach those calculations to the data.

Comment: @Caleth I can see where you're coming from, but shouldn't a triangle just be a triangle, independent of what you calculate about it and how you're calculating it?

Comment: @JansthcirlU Maybe not if you have multiple sources giving you different representations of triangle data.

Comment: I don't think this idea of using the strategy pattern is a good idea. Once you have a triangle object constructed, assuming there is some normalized internal representation, picking different approaches to calculate the area becomes obsolete. And when there are different internal representations, the triangle object should be able to pick one algorithm which fits best.

Comment: @DocBrown: my initial thought was the same. I only offered it as a suggestion in case there was a need to compare algorithms. Although if that is the case, I feel like static methods that accept a Triangle object would suffice. The Triangle object should expose properties that return the calculated values required by the different algorithms.